# assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]

Tags: c, gtk3, glade

```
char *inputtxt;
void encrypt()
{

    inputtxt = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY (input_));
    unsigned char key[AES_SIZE+1] = { "YELLOW SUBMARINE" };
    memcpy(inputtxt,"gg",32);
    memcpy(key, "HERE IS MY KEY!!", 16);
    unsigned char iv[AES_SIZE+1] = { "HERE IS MY IV!!!" };
    aes_cbc_encrypt(inputtxt, key, 32, iv);
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(outputk_), inputtxt);
```

I cant seem to get this to work at all, i get the error on line "inputtxt = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY (input_));

Comment: Suggest reading the [gtk_entry_get_text manual](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.Entry.get_text.html): *"Returns: const gchar \* A pointer to the contents of the widget as a string. This string points to internally allocated storage in the widget and must not be freed, modified or stored.*". That is, the real problem is that you are attempting to modify `inputtxt` which is specifically not allowed.

Comment: Never reuse an `iv`.

Comment: if i cant modify inputtxt how would i go about further with my code

Answer (score 2):

The signature of `gtk_entry_get_text` is

```
const gchar* gtk_entry_get_text(GtkEntry *entry);
```

In consequence

```
char *inputtxt;
```

should be

```
const char *inputtxt;
```

and you are not allowed to use `memcpy` with it.

Anyway, what are you trying to achieve with

```
memcpy(inputtxt,"gg",32);
```

??

The third parameter is *Number of bytes to copy.* You can not copy 32 bytes from the literal "gg".

Comment: how would i define number of bytes?

Comment: `memcpy(key, "HERE IS MY KEY!!", 16);` is fine because the literal length is 17, so you are copying the whole string except the trailing NUL, but in the case of "gg" you can not copy more than 2 or 3 bytes (if you are interested in the NUL) and using 32 bytes you are accessing outside of the bounds of the literal. As I said in the answer, you can not use `memcpy` with a constant, but you can duplicate and modify the string, take a look to [g_strdup_printf](https://people.gnome.org/~ryanl/glib-docs/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strdup-printf)

Comment: i changed memcpy to g_trdup_printf andfunction aes_cbc_encrypt wants unsigned char*plain_text. which gves error  passing argument 1 of 'aes_cbc_encrypt' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]

Comment: @David Ranieri – I didn't address you with my response to the comment above. :-) But thanks to you, I realize that even the commenter didn't mention `AES_cbc_encrypt`, but rather `aes_cbc_encrypt`, so I'll delete my response above.

Comment: @Peter Bjørholm Hansen - Where and how is `aes_cbc_encrypt` defined?